# Loading Jquery UI before Jquery

Tags: jquery

When I load JQuery UI before JQuery, my script does not function at all. For example

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

The above would not work. But this would work

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Why is this?

Comment: While programming you have to use serialization.. executing one by one,   load that first. browser starts executing your page from the first line..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `jQuery UI` need `jQuery` library.

See in error log, `$ is undefined`, because they are not functions like `funcName()` but jQuery functions `$.funcName()` with other jQuery functions required.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now load `jQuery`. But error is still from `UI`.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Aren't both just a set of defined functions?

Comment: @Leon Helmsley jqueryUI use function defined in jquery

Comment: Yes, but `jQuery` plugins. They are not functions like `funcName()` but `$.funcName()`

Answer (score 1):

First is the jquery libray because all the basic selectors, manipulators, and other basic functions are written in

```
jquery.js
```

So jquery-ui will make use of the functions available in jquery.js to create any plugins like

1. autocomplte
2. datepicker
   ...
   ...

Answer (score 1):

The jqueryui file needs jquery library to work properly. So you must add jquery library before including jqueryui file